# Delete log file use by another process

Tags: php, node.js, delete-file

I create log file from this command

```
shell_exec("node  node-server\socket.server.js > node.log");
```

and I want remove this file without stop service.
when I use this command

```
 unlink('node.log');
```

show me this error

> unlink(node.log): Permission denied

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13594898/permission-denied-php-unlink
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12148229/how-to-get-permission-to-use-unlink
possible duplicates

Comment: I can not use shell command