# How to delete old file from the folder while updating?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to delete the old file from the folder ie, if  I update an image the old one remains as it is in the folder and a new one is get uploaded.

Here updating is done fine but after frequent updating number of files is increasing .

This is the code for selecting the content from the database and also for updating

```
public function select_testimonials($id)
{
    $this->session->set_userdata('id',$id );
    $query = $this->cl_testimonials_model->select($id);
    $data1['selectdata'] = $query->result();
        // $this->index();
    $query = $this->db->get("cl_testimonials");
    $data1['records'] = $query->result();
    $this->load->view('admin/testimonials/testimonials_edit',$data1);
}



public function update_testimonials()   
{   
    $id = $this->input->post("id");
    if ($this->input->post('submit')=="update")
    {
        if(!empty($_FILES['picture']['name']))
        {
            $config['upload_path'] = 'uploads/images/testimonials';
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png|gif';
            $config['file_name'] = $_FILES['picture']['name'];

            //Load upload library and initialize configuration

            $this->load->library('upload',$config);
            $this->upload->initialize($config);

            if($this->upload->do_upload('picture'))
            {
                $uploadData = $this->upload->data();
                $picture = $uploadData['file_name'];
            }

        }

        //Prepare array of user data
        $data = array('name' => $this->input->post('name'),'content' => $this->input->post('content'),'picture' => $picture);  

        //Pass user data to model
        $insertUserData = $this->cl_testimonials_model->update($id,$data);
        }
        //Storing insertion status message.
        if(isset($insertUserData))
             {
                $data['message']="* testimonials updated successfully.";
             }
             else
             {
                $data['message']="* Some problems occured, please try again.";
             }


    $query = $this->db->get("cl_testimonials");
    $data['records'] = $query->result();
    $this->load->view('admin/testimonials/testimonials_listing',$data); 
}
```

Comment: use php  ```unlink() ``` to delete file. Ref - http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php

Comment: before updating file name in table first fetch its old name from db and once  new file updated successfully then delete old one .

Answer (score 0):

Fetch Existing testimonial picture path by id, update, then use `unlink('old file path')`

More here : [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11463581/how-to-use-unlink-function)

Answer (score 0):

Use the unlink(); function in php. it is applicable also in Codeigniter.

```
unlink("target path/".$file name);
```